# code python the frequency of words try/except

Tags: python

I don't understand the following piece of code in python:

```
def frequency(text):
if text == "":
    return ""

cuvinte = text.split(" ")
frecv = {}

for cuv in cuvinte:
    try:
        frecv[cuv] += 1
    except:
        frecv[cuv] = 1

print (frecv)
```

For example if i run:

```
frequency('zero one two three one four two one five')
```

it will show us:

```
{'four': 1, 'three': 1, 'two': 2, 'one': 3, 'five': 1, 'zero': 1}
```

But why? What's the thing with

```
 try:
        frecv[cuv] += 1
 except:
        frecv[cuv] = 1  ?
```

Comment: That's fine that you are asking this question, but please _do not use that code in your own work!_ Use Counters or `frecv[cuv] = frecv.get(cuv,0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

This handles `KeyError` exception. `frecv[cuv] += 1` is equivalent to `frecv[cuv] = frecv[cuv] + 1` which means `cuv` key must be present in the dictionary. So the code can be read as "If there is a value for `cuv`, add 1 to it; else set it to 1".

A more elegant way to write this would be

```
try:
    frecv[cuv] += 1
except KeyError:
    frecv[cuv] = 1
```

Comment: Your explanation of the behavior is correct, but actually the advice to use exceptions at all (even localizing it to `KeyError`) is not good here. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, as Evert pointed out in the comments it's better to use defaultdict in this case.

Comment: You could add "A better way to deal with the exceptions would be ..." (your code here) _then_ show better alternatives (for the +1)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `frecv[cuv] += 1` that is actually retrieving the current value of `frecv[cuv]`, adding 1 to it and then assigning it to `frecv[cuv]`. When `frecv[cuv]` does not have any value yet, it can therefore not be retrieved, hence an exception (`KeyError`) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`try..except..` is the [exception handling mechanism in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

The block means that, when `freecv[cuv] += 1` fails (on this case, when there isn't any `cuv` in `freecv`), it runs `freecv[cuv] = 1`. Simply it first tries to increment the count for the word, and when it fails(because that word isn't added yet) exists, it uses 1.

By the way, that code can be written much simpler:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def frequency(text):
...     return Counter(text.split(" "))
...
>>> frequency('zero one two three one four two one five')
Counter({'one': 3, 'two': 2, 'three': 1, 'four': 1, 'zero': 1, 'five': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The try..except is a very lazy way of handling the case where the *frecv* dictionary does not contain the key referenced by *cuv*. A better way would be to write it like this:

```
if cuv not in frecv:
    frecv[cuv] = 1
else:
    frecv[cuv] += 1
```

The reason the try..except works here is because, if the *cuv* key is not present in the dictionary, a KeyError exception will be thrown. In that case, the code will set if with the default value of 1.

The reason that such a try..except case is a (very) bad practice, is because it may actually catch other errors as well. Imagine this was the code:

```
try:
    freqv[cuv] += 1
except:
    frecv[cuv] = 1
```

Notice the typo in the try..except block? This would be caught by the exception handler and all your dictionary values would end up as being 1.